# How to implement Pushnotification in Android Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm new to Phonegap. I've an application in which i wanted to add a person as a buddy & all the details will sit in to my database but as soon as i add him a message should send to that person in his android mobile (acts as external notification- status bar notification) who has this app installed. How will send him a message which acts as an external notification for him in android using phonegap.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1):

To use Android push notifications, you have to implement an application that uses the [Google Cloud Messaging service](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), which could be used by your PhoneGap app.

If you don't want to implement the application by yourself, you could use third party services, such as [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi david, Thanks for the answer but that is there in android native app. i wanted to implement in phonegap. Can you please suggest me how will i implement in phonegap. Also there is a plugin in phonegap for pushnotification, i have implemented that using GCM but im not getting the overall flow of the functionality....

Comment: @user2003570 nope, if you implement the server to comunicate with GMC you can use it however you want (through Javascript AJAX calls according to your requirements), and if you use Urban Airship, it has a Javascript API (https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client:+Phonegap:+Javascript+API)

Comment: @user2003570 You can implement native GCM for android and create a plugin for that in phonegap. I have implemented this in my application and it works really well.